# The search is very slow in Clash of clans

Tags: clash-of-clans

When I reach the Legend league the search become very slow, and it may take more than 2 hours to find town to attack.

Can I speed this up?

Comment: Why the downvote??

Answer (score 1):

No.

That's pretty much all there is to it - as you reach higher leagues there are less people in those leagues to pit you against, and thus it takes longer to find someone that is not just the correct rating but also is not online and does not have an active shield or guard.

Of course if you want more battles, you could always drop back down a group.